# how to show Alert while the input text data is changing with actionscript 2?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs3

i want to make an input text validation with FLASH ActionScript 2.
The input text only displaying numbers above 5, so if i try to input number 0,1,2,3,4, the Alert will pop up and give an information that the data should be above 5.

i want the validation processing while the input text is changing, because i dont use any button as the trigger.

```
import mx.controls.Alert;

var tiListener:Object = new Object();

tiListener.change = function(evt_obj:Object)
{
   if(inputText.text < 5)
   {
      trace("Numbers below 5 are not allowed");
      Alert.show("Numbers below 5 are not allowed", "Error");
      inputText.setFocus(); 
   };
};

proj.addEventListener("change", tiListener);
```

Trace output is working well, but the Alert not shown.
Any body have any solution?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The type of your inputText text is `string`, and you want it to be `number`. Use the `parseInt` method to convert your string to an `integer`:

```
inputText.onChanged = function(tf:TextField) 
{
    if (parseInt(tf.text) < 5)
   {
      trace("Numbers below 5 are not allowed");
      Alert.show("Numbers below 5 are not allowed", "Error");
      inputText.setFocus();
   }
}
```

Place this code into your function, and that will be more clear:

```
trace(typeof(tf.text));
trace(typeof(parseInt(tf.text)));
```

Comment: yes it is.. i just add `parseInt` method, and it work well.. but finally i decide to use a button to trigger the validation function.. because if i still using `onChange` event, i have to add a timer function for checkhing the input data is still under 5 or it actually 10.. so if i type 1 the validation doesn't suddenly working..

Comment: @user3931626 The type of your variable was actually the reason why your code didn't work.